# How to capture wireless packets over Ethernet port along with Wired

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, wireshark, sniffing

I am trying to capture and analyze my network traffic. We have a wireless router and it have clients as both wired and wireless.

My Kali computer which is connected to the router over **Ethernet** port and with **Promiscuous mode** ON.

While the packets are captured and analyzed in `wireshark`, I noticed in Wireshark, the Wired clients traffic is captured with all protocols but for wireless clients only `MDNS` protocol packets, but not any `TCP` or `UDP` packets.

I am trying to understand, what is the reason, behind not getting Wireless clients packets along with wired when packet capture is running on Ethernet Promiscuous mode?

Is there any other way to accomplish this - capture both wired and wireless packets on Ethernet Promiscuous mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply said, the wireless packets are sent using a different medium, since you are listening on Ethernet. Additionally, 802.11 is encrypted using using e.g. WPA2.

So if you want the actual wireless frames you need to decrypt the frames and listen using a wifi interface opened in monitor mode. `Protocols > IEEE 802.11` in Wiresharks preferences allows to set a decryption key but deriving/obtaining that key might be difficult depending on your situation.

Another option is to sniff on the router (if supported by your CPE), this might be more accessible but you lose a certain degree of reality since you might see adapted frames on the sub-network layers.